# What is a remote Docker interpreter when you make a container?

Tags: python, django, docker, pycharm, interpreter

For example, if you're making a container for a Django project, is a remote interpreter a python interpreter that is stored in the Docker cloud and not on your PC?

So when someone runs the container on another PC, it will use the same remote interpreter designated for this project from the Docker cloud?

Comment: What's docker cloud? Do you mean DockerHub (which is a repository of _images_, not running containers) or some service running docker like Azure/AWS etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You docker docker container is like a box which contains python interpreter + django source code + anything else.

So when you make Docker container with your Django app you obviously have a Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.8.0-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/app/
```

and `docker-compose.yml`

version: '3.7'

```
services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
```

So when someone runs the container on another PC, it will use the same local interpreter from the container.

Comment: So why is the interpreter called "remote" (source: https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/12/using-docker-in-pycharm/) when it is actually located inside the container?

Comment: because it's somewhere in container :) I would not mix the pycharm's terms  with the docker core. The whole point of the containers is to pack and put all the dependent code as an independent "box"